# Sporadic haproxy NOSRV errors in localhost when hitting dockerized HTTP server

Tags: docker, curl, networking, localhost, haproxy

I was trying to demo something, locally, using haproxy. So, I spun up two HTTP servers using Docker host netowrking which each listen on a different port (9998 and 9999) as follows:

```
docker run -it --env PORT=9998 --rm --name web-test-2 --network=host -p 9998:9998 crccheck/hello-world

docker run -it --env PORT=9999 --rm --name web-test-3 --network=host -p 9999:9999 crccheck/hello-world
```

Then I started `haproxy` using the following config:

```
$ cat haproxy.cfg                          
defaults
  log global
  option httplog

frontend default
  log stdout local0 debug
  bind :9990

  acl ACL_foo_servers req.hdr(host) -i foo:9990
  use_backend foo_servers if ACL_foo_servers

  acl ACL_bar_servers req.hdr(host) -i bar:9990
  use_backend bar_servers if ACL_bar_servers

backend foo_servers
   mode http
   server s1 127.0.0.1:9998

backend bar_servers
   mode http
   server s1 127.0.0.1:9999
```

(so `haproxy -- ./haproxy.cfg`)

Then, I would test the HAProxy ACL using the following `curl` statements

```bash
curl --connect-timeout 1.0 -v -k foo:9990
curl --connect-timeout 1.0 -v -k bar:9990
```

It's routing successfully when the request succeeds. However, a lot of the time my requests fail. Below are the log outputs after 2 `curl` executions: the first failed and the second succeeded.

```
$ haproxy -- ./haproxy.cfg
[NOTICE]   (733479) : haproxy version is 2.7.3-1065b10
[NOTICE]   (733479) : path to executable is ./result/bin/haproxy
[WARNING]  (733479) : config : parsing [./haproxy.cfg:3] : 'option httplog' not usable with frontend 'default' (needs 'mode http'). Falling back to 'option tcplog'.
[WARNING]  (733479) : config : missing timeouts for frontend 'default'.
   | While not properly invalid, you will certainly encounter various problems
   | with such a configuration. To fix this, please ensure that all following
   | timeouts are set to a non-zero value: 'client', 'connect', 'server'.
[WARNING]  (733479) : config : missing timeouts for backend 'foo_servers'.
   | While not properly invalid, you will certainly encounter various problems
   | with such a configuration. To fix this, please ensure that all following
   | timeouts are set to a non-zero value: 'client', 'connect', 'server'.
[WARNING]  (733479) : config : missing timeouts for backend 'bar_servers'.
   | While not properly invalid, you will certainly encounter various problems
   | with such a configuration. To fix this, please ensure that all following
   | timeouts are set to a non-zero value: 'client', 'connect', 'server'.
<134>Apr 26 12:40:29 haproxy[733479]: 127.0.0.1:55880 [26/Apr/2023:12:40:29.485] default default/<NOSRV> -1/-1/0 0 SC 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
<134>Apr 26 12:40:31 haproxy[733479]: 127.0.0.1:33380 [26/Apr/2023:12:40:31.284] default foo_servers/s1 0/0/0 622 -- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
```

You can see the failure log cases look like

```
<134>Apr 26 12:40:29 haproxy[733479]: 127.0.0.1:55880 [26/Apr/2023:12:40:29.485] default default/<NOSRV> -1/-1/0 0 SC 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
```

and the success log cases look like

```
<134>Apr 26 12:40:31 haproxy[733479]: 127.0.0.1:33380 [26/Apr/2023:12:40:31.284] default foo_servers/s1 0/0/0 622 -- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
```

I understand from https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/1-6r2/onepage/#8.9 that SC means that the server connection failed. But, I don't understand what could be causing this sporadic connection failure or how to fix it. My guess is that something with `docker` `host` networking and `localhost` and the kernel is causing this. But, I have no idea.

**Update: I played around with both `timeout connect|client|server` to no avail. But, setting `mode http` completely resolves this. I don't know what the default mode is: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/1-6r2/onepage/#4.2-mode . But, this totally fixes it. I would love an explanation as to why this fixes the problem. To be clear: The working config looks like**

```
defaults
  mode http
  #timeout connect 500ms
  #timeout client 500ms
  #timeout server 500ms
  log global
  option httplog
frontend default
  log stdout local0 debug
  bind :9990
  acl ACL_foo_servers req.hdr(host) -i foo:9990
  use_backend foo_servers if ACL_foo_servers
  acl ACL_bar_servers req.hdr(host) -i bar:9990
  use_backend bar_servers if ACL_bar_servers
backend foo_servers
   mode http
   server s1 127.0.0.1:9998
backend bar_servers
   mode http
   server s1 127.0.0.1:9999
```